# Retrieve same column twice from table one with different conditions from table 2

Tags: sql

i am a bit novice in SQL I have two tables one ManagedSystem with the attribute AssetName and ManagedSystemID and the other Managed Account with the attributes AccountName, AccountID, ParentAccountID, and ManagedSystemID. The tables are connected to the ManagedSystemID attribute, we want to show that if an asset in the 1st column has an account that has a parent ID (2nd column), that Parent Asset will show in the third column.

### Table1:

| AccountName | ManagedSID | AccountID | ParentAccountID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AccountName1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| AccountName1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| AccountName2 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| AccountName2 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| AccountName3 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| AccountName3 | 2 | 6 | 0 |
| AccountName3 | 3 | 7 | 5 |

### Tabla2:

| AssetName | ManagedSID |
| --- | --- |
| Asset1 | 1 |
| Asset2 | 2 |
| Asset3 | 3 |

### Results:

| ChildAsset | AccountName | ParentAsset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Asset2 | AccountName1 | Asset1 |
| Asset2 | AccountName2 | Asset1 |
| Asset3 | AccountName3 | Asset1 |

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

[These are the two tables and the results we are trying to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Twf2.png)

I tied this but it doesn´t work

```
SELECT 
  pmm.PmmManagedSystem.Name as 'Asset Name', 
  pmm.PmmManagedAccount.AccountName, 
  (
    SELECT 
      TOP 1 pmm.PmmManagedSystem.Name 
    FROM 
      pmm.PmmManagedAccount 
      INNER JOIN pmm.PmmManagedSystem ON pmm.PmmManagedAccount.ManagedSystemID = pmm.PmmManagedSystem.ManagedSystemID 
    WHERE 
      pmm.PmmManagedAccount.ManagedAccountID = pmm.PmmManagedAccount.ParentAccountID
  ) as 'Master Server' 
FROM 
  pmm.PmmManagedSystem 
  INNER JOIN pmm.PmmManagedAccount ON pmm.PmmManagedSystem.ManagedSystemID = pmm.PmmManagedAccount.ManagedSystemID
```

Comment:  Please never expect us to work with [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data or code, it cannot be consumed, used or searched on; please use *text* for text.

Comment: I'd say if you'd edit your question and add the `Create Table` statements and a few `Insert Into` lines and show the expected result, then your Q would be more self-explaining

Comment: Thanks, both of you for your comments, it's my first time posting a question here, I will try to edit it according to them

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your tables aliases, especially when you use the same table more than once. How else is the runtime expected to know which instance you're referring to? For example;

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table2 AS child_sys
INNER JOIN
  table1 AS child_acc
    ON child_acc.ManagedSystemID = child_sys.ManagedSystemID
INNER JOIN
  table1 AS parent_acc
    ON parent_acc.AccountID = child_acc.ParentAccountID
INNER JOIN
  table2 AS parent_sys
    ON parent_sys.ManagedSystemID = parent_acc.ManagedSystemID
```